# Given a type ExpressionType.MemberAccess, how do i get the field value?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I am parsing an Expression Tree. Given a NodeType of ExpressionType.MemberAccess, how do I get the value of that Field?

From C# MSDN docs: 
MemberAccess is A node that represents reading from a field or property.

A code snippet would be incredibly, incredibly helpful. Thanks in advance!!!

My code looks something like this:

```
public static List<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExp) 
{
//the expression is indeed a binary expression in this case
BinaryExpression expBody = filterExp.Body as BinaryExpression;

if (expBody.Left.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess) 
  //do something with ((MemberExpressionexpBody.Left).Name

//right hand side is indeed member access. in fact, the value comes from //aspdroplist.selectedvalue            
if (expBody.Right.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
{
   //how do i get the value of aspdroplist.selected value?? note: it's non-static                        
}

//return a list
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[updated for clarity]

First; cast the `Expression` to a `MemberExpression`.

A `MemberExpression` has two things of interest:

- .Member - the `PropertyInfo` / `FieldInfo` to the member
- .Expression - the expression to evaluate to get the "obj" for the .Member

i.e. if you can evaluate the `.Expression` to "obj", and the `.Member` is a `FieldInfo`, then you can get the actual value via `.GetValue(obj)` on the `FieldInfo` (and `PropertyInfo` is very similar).

The problem is that evaluating the `.Expression` is very tricky ;-p

Obviously you get lucky if it turns out to be a `ConstantExpression` - but in most cases it isn't; it could be a `ParameterExpression` (in which case you'll need to know the actual parameter value that you want to evaluate), or any other combination of `Expression`s.

In many cases, a simple (perhaps lazy) option is to use `.Compile()` to get the .NET framework to do the heavy lifting; you can then evaluate the lambda as a typed delegate (passing in any parameters that the lambda requires). This isn't always an option, however.

To show how complex this is; consider this trivial example (where I've hard-coded at every step, rather than testing etc):

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo {Bar = "abc"};
        Expression<Func<string>> func = () => foo.Bar;

        MemberExpression outerMember = (MemberExpression)func.Body;
        PropertyInfo outerProp = (PropertyInfo) outerMember.Member;
        MemberExpression innerMember = (MemberExpression)outerMember.Expression;
        FieldInfo innerField = (FieldInfo)innerMember.Member;
        ConstantExpression ce = (ConstantExpression) innerMember.Expression;
        object innerObj = ce.Value;
        object outerObj = innerField.GetValue(innerObj);
        string value = (string) outerProp.GetValue(outerObj, null);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marc. THe value of .Expression property is ... something more interesting:  {value(ASP.usercontrols_mycontro_ascx).controlname}

Comment: i'm doing a lot with generics and reflection so retrieving the value via propertyinfo/fieldinfo isn't working because i'm not sure where to pull the referencing object from ... can i pull that from memberexpression or methodinfo?

Comment: It will work... but the problem is you need to evaluate the .Expression as a value to feed in as the "obj" for FieldInfo/PropertyInfo. Can you not just use .Compile() and execute the lambda as a delegate? A lot easier than parsing...

Comment: Note that if the lambda is parameterised, but you don't have the specific parameter - then you will struggle... but things like ConstantExpression should work themselves out OK.

Comment: Thank you so much Marc!!! really ... above and beyond here. 

ultimately the problem is the left hand side is a binaryexpression ... and the right hand side isn't a constantexpression. i'm going to update my question with some code

Answer (score 25):

thank you so so much to Marc Gravell above. I really appreciated his help.

It turns out, in my case. the problem can be solved via:

```
object value = Expression.Lambda(expBody.Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Thanks again Mark!

Comment: or better 
`object value = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(expBody.Right, typeof(object))).Compile().Invoke()`

Comment: The sad part: it's very slow.