# How to evaluate a string containing local variable names as code in C#

Tags: c#

I need a function to evaluate the value of a string as C# code. The string contains local variables and arithmetic operations, and the function works as if the string is the code in the same place. Something like:

```
int a = ...; int b = ...; int c = ...;
...
int result = Eval("a+b+c"); // should return current value a+b+c
```

We can limit the discussion to the simple types like int and arithmetic operations between them. Is it possible to do that in C#/.Net? It is acceptable to pass in context parameter to the function, say, containing the name and value of all required variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you take a look at DataTable.Compute method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207809/evalstring-to-c-sharp-code there is a link to a nice project Eval Expression.NET

Comment: You can't really call `Eval("a+b+c")` method without passing local variables into it too, unless this is some kind of code injection instead of method call. If you are able to create environment, then codedom is easy way: just create a long string, contatining class definition and fields with local variable values and wrap equation into a method call. Compile in memory, run, done.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/333737/9681220

Answer (score -1):

Prepend script that declares and initializes the variables. For example, if you wish to pass a variable named `a` into the script, do this:

```
var script = string.Format("var a = {0}\r\n", a) + script;
var result = Eval(script);
```

Comment: what is Eval()??

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought OP was asking this: Given the ability to compile and execute a string containing c# code, how can the program pass in local variables?"

Comment: *"I need a function"* - said OP. Since you don't know what is `Eval()`, why do you think it supports what you suggest as the answer?

Comment: I assumed that `Eval()` was a placeholder for a compilation function, sort of as if the OP were using `Foo()` but with a more representative name. As I said, i may have misunderstood the question.