# Evaluating an arbitrary string expression in c#

Tags: c#, string, comparison, ncalc

I have a method that needs to return true or false based upon a string expression that is passed in to it.  The string expression could look like:

("ASDF"=="A" || "BED"!="BED") && (5>=2)

or any valid C# expression that evaluates to a Boolean result.  I only need to support basic string and math comparison operators plus parentheses.  I have tried NCalc but when I pass it this:

"GEN"=="GEN" || "GEN"=="GENINTER"

it generates the error
System.ArgumentException: Parameter was not defined (Parameter 'GEN')
at NCalc.Domain.EvaluationVisitor.Visit(Identifier parameter)

when I use the following code:

NCalc.Expression e = new(filterExpression, EvaluateOptions.IgnoreCase);
var filterResultObject =e.Evaluate();

Any thoughts appreciated on how to evaluate an arbitrary expression since I will not know the expression until run time.

Greg

Comment: Have a read through [Rick Strahl's blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jun/07/Runtime-CSharp-Code-Compilation-Revisited-for-Roslyn) on runtime code generation

Comment: Does the expression contain only string and integer literals, or do you need variables, too?

Comment: Dis you have a look at similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580598/c-sharp-evaluate-a-string-expression-and-return-the-result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207809/evalstring-to-c-sharp-code

Comment: Evaluating user supplied expressions as c# code seem like it might be potentially dangerous. Using a specialized parser should be safer if that is a concern.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  Yes, only strings, integers, floats.... no variables.   Since the incoming expression is evaluated, I agree that the solution needs to be safe to prevent intentional malformed expressions from causing safety concerns.  This is why I'm looking for an 'evaluator' that takes care of parsing, performing the operations, and resulting the answer rather than using runtime code injection which exposes the dangers of intentional injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that NCalc will properly evaluate the strings but only if they are single quoted such as !('GEN'=='GEN').  If the strings are double quoted, the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

For your example you can use [NFun](https://github.com/tmteam/NFun) package like this:

```
string str =  "\"ASDF\"==\"A\" || \"BED\"!=\"BED\") && (5>=2)"
bool result = Funny.Calc<bool>(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso) library. Example usage:

```cs
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
bool result = (bool)interpreter.Eval("\"GEN\" == \"GEN\" || \"GEN\" == \"GENINTER\"");
```

They also have an [online tool](https://dynamic-expresso.azurewebsites.net/) to test expressions.